# How do I choose a random number from a list?

Tags: c++, random

I am creating a number-guessing game where the player has to guess a randomly generated number but I don't know how to choose a random number.

I have a variable called truenumber which is equal to a list of numbers, what I want to do is make it randomly choose from the list and compare it to the user's input.

```
    int truenumber; 
    truenumber = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10;
```

So how do I make it pick a random number from the list each time?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    string message = "Hello";
    cout << message << endl;
    cout << "Lets play a game" << endl;
    cout << "Try to guess the number!" << endl;
 
    int truenumber; 
    truenumber = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10;
    int number;
    cin >> number;

    if (number = truenumber) {   
        cout << "You got it right!" << endl;
    }
    else if (number > truenumber) {
        cout  << "Too high" << endl;
        cin >> number;
    }
    else (number < truenumber) {
        cout << "Too low" << endl;
        cin >> number;
    }
    
}
```

I wasn't expecting this to work since truenumber doesn't have an actual value and I was trying to find a solution online but only found really complex solutions that didn't match my ideas.

Comment: "*I don't know how to choose a random number*" - use a random-number generator, such as from the [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) library. In this case, put all of your numbers in a container, and then generate a random index that is within the container's range. "*I have a variable called truenumber which is equal to a list of numbers*" - no, you don't. `truenumber = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10;` doesn't do what you think it does. The value of `truenumber` will just be just `10`.  To hold all of the numbers, you need to use an array instead.

Comment: Its `9`. https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: Put all numbers in an **array**. [Shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) the array. Get the first value of the array.

Comment: [std::vector<int>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)  would be a much better start. Then have a look at the [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header. The C++ standard library has a lot for you to (re-)use, if it is there... don't invent it yourself.

Comment: @PepijnKramer or `std::array<int, 10>` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes for a fixed numbers of numbers thats true :)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Check array or list size
2. Use rand() method from standard library

You can do it like this `value = rand() % listSize`. This would give you a random number from 0 to listSize.

Hope this would help.

Comment: This is an approach that has been used a lot. But this PRNG is not really strong, especially when modulo'ed against a small size

Comment: @Jeffrey -- it's large sizes that get a worse result with `%`, not small sizes. And that's an issue regardless of the generator you're using. `rand()` is good enough for beginners, and easier to get started with than the stuff in the `<random>` header.

Comment: @Jeffrey -- For sure it's not suitable for cutting-edge technology. But for the number-guessing game, it's an acceptable solution (if you want to start and focus on other things).

Answer (score 0):

To get a random number you can use rand() or std::rand()

You will also need to use srand() to seed the random number (get a new random number)

To get a random number in a range, you can use the module operator.

https://godbolt.org/z/hfMaxGYjr